# Unity Networking - Rigidbody2D

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, lag, unity3d-2dtools

I'm working on a multiplayer soccer game (1 vs 1). 
- There is a ball in scene and a rigidbody2D is attached to it.
- Player1(rigidbody2D) is instantiating with Network.Instantiated when server is registered.
- Player2(rigidbody2D) is instantiating with Network.Instantiated when client is connected to server.

- Player1 sends its position with RPC in Update function.
- Player2 sends its position with RPC in Update function.
- Server sends ball's position and rotation with RPC in Update function.

In this case there is jittering problem in opposite side (I mean, while controlling Player1, which is server, on client side Player1's movement is not smooth and while controlling Player2, which is client, on server side Player2's movement is not smooth) 
This is my first problem, i'm not sure it will continue when i build and run it on phones.

My second and the biggest problem is Player2's rigidbody2D is NOT working well, i mean, when he hits the ball, OnCollisionEnter2D function is WORKING (there is an AddForce line in there), but the standard rigidbody2D behavior is not working, when i walk to ball, Player2 and the ball just stops when i delete the OnCollisionEnter2D function! ---- But Player1's rigidbody2D works pretty well. So, i couldn't figure why it is not working well, the ball isn't being instantiated on server or client side, there is no reason to act different to each player for ball...

Please help me with this two problems. In addition, if you have any better idea to build this type of game's network structure please tell me.

Comment: 1) search for "client-side prediction". Be prepared to catch your jaw before it hits the table. 2) If I got this right you're essentially running 2 separate physics simulations on both computers. Any lag introduced through transmitting position etc updates to the client will desynchronize the two simulations (search for "game network synchronization" and similar). You need an authoritative server respectively a proper client-server model (look that up, too). 3) If you feel like a wasps nest fell on your head, that's normal. Welcome to the world of multiplayer game (physics) programming. ;)

Comment: If this wasn't clear: the question is far, far too broad for stackoverflow. In essence if you want to get this right you need to do a lot of research and tackle one sub-problem at a time. Perhaps you can use a networking framework for unity (photon?) that eases the synchronization and perhaps even prediction part.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for response, you are absolutely right on your words. I thought that structure but it is not that easy to implement :) So, is your suggestion that: "2 players are both clients, and server does all the physics stuff" did i get it? Unfortunately I don't have any budget for 3rd party networking assets btw.

Comment: one side does physics, the other does not - you can make one client act as the "server" or you can have an actual server but then you'd have to have a webserver accessible from the internet (but the server probably can't be implemented in unity)